# Apart from being maxima, minima or inflection point, can a critical point be anything else?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

**Question:**

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} 6, & x\le1\\7-x, & x\gt1\end{cases}$ then for $f(x), x=1$ is

A) a point of local maxima

B) a point of local minima

C) neither a point of local maxima nor minima

D) a stationary point

**My Attempt:**

The graph of $f(x)$ has a sharp edge at $x=1$. So, it's not a stationary point but a critical point.

Also, $f(1+h)\lt f(1)$, so, $x=1$ is not a point of minima.

And $f(1-h)$ is not less than $f(1)$, so, $x=1$ is not a maxima either. Or is it?

I am confused between A) and C).

If it is indeed C) then what will we call $x=1?$

If a critical point is neither maxima nor minima nor inflection then what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Your function $f$ isn't differentiable at $x = 1$. A point $a$ in the domain of the function $f$ is a critical point iff $f'(a) = 0$ (Some people do define a critical point to be a point where either the derivative is zero or the function is not differentiable). In this case:
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} 0 = 0$$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1-x}{x-1} = -1$$
Since these two derivatives don't coincide, the function isn't differentiable there. Now, observe that when $x > 1$, we have that $-x < -1$. So, $7-x < 6$. In other words, at $x = 1$, $f$ has a local maximum.

This will depend a little bit on your definition of local maximum. Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open interval $I$ and let $a \in I$. Usually, we say that $a$ is a local maximum of $I$ iff there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta) \subseteq I$ and:
$$\forall x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta): f(x) \leq f(a)$$
If you demand that the inequality be strict, then $x = 1$ is not a local maximum and certainly, it isn't a local minimum. You'll have to check your definitions to determine what's the answer in this case.

Comment: thank you . . .

Comment: points where the derivative is zeto are usually called "stationary points". Most (not "some") include points in the domain where the derivative does not exist under the definition of "critical point".  E.g., that is what is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Sure, I wasn't really going off of what has been said on Wikipedia